# Pass appropriate amount and type of arguments to a function

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14, metaprogramming

I'm wondering if such a thing is even possible in C++11, passing appropriate amount and type of arguments to a function when for example you have:

```
template <typename R, typename ... Types> 
constexpr std::integral_constant<unsigned, sizeof ...(Types)> getArgumentCount( R(*f)(Types ...))
{
   return std::integral_constant<unsigned, sizeof ...(Types)>{};
}

void foo(std::string first, double second, std::string third);
void bar(std::string first, std::string second);
void baz(std::string first, int c);

void passArgs(std::vector<std::string> arguments)
{
    //Get arguments count for function foo, do the same for the others
    size_t foo_count = decltype(getArgumentCount(foo))::value;
    //Here pass appropriate amount of arguments to foo,bar and baz and 
    //convert to appropriate type using for example std::stoi and 
    //std::stod when the argument is int or double
    Magic(foo,arguments,foo_count);
}

int main()
{


}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What you are trying to do is quite complex and problematic. If possible it would be easier to use inheritance; a base class which has the methods numArgs() and argType( unsigned int index ) that you can use, and then either perform some function trickery in assembly (pushing args onto the stack), or make a templated derived class that you then downcast to to call the function.

Comment: How are you supposed to know whether the string `"3.54"` is the text `"3.54"` or a `double`?  Just assume anything that can be an int is, failing that a double, failing that a string?  You can use `boost::lexical_cast<>` (or your own implementation - takes ~5 lines with `istringstream`) for the conversions.  You're going to need some kind of `switch` between the function calls though, or perhaps a numeric encoding of number of parameters and their types that you can pass to a template that knows the available functions and have it choose the one with matching parameter list.

Comment: @Tont D You know what the type must be from the function signature, for example for `foo` the `first` must be `string`, `second` is `double` and `third` is `string`. The arguments are ordered correctly in the `std::vector<std::string> arguments`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <cstddef>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
T convert(const std::string&);

template <>
int convert<int>(const std::string& s)
{
    return std::stoi(s);
}

template <>
std::string convert<std::string>(const std::string& s)
{
    return s;
}

template <>
double convert<double>(const std::string& s)
{
    return std::stod(s);
}

template <typename R, typename... Args, std::size_t... Is>
void Magic(const std::vector<std::string>& arguments, R(*f)(Args...), std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    f(convert<typename std::decay<Args>::type>(arguments[Is])...);
}

template <typename R, typename... Args>
void passArgs(const std::vector<std::string>& arguments, R(*f)(Args...))
{
    Magic(arguments, f, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args)>{});
}
```

Test:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> arguments{"abc", "3.14", "def"};
    passArgs(arguments, &foo);
    passArgs(arguments, &bar);
    passArgs(arguments, &baz);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8fa052ae8d4eab0c)

---

For a C++11-compliant implementation, you could employ the blow implementation of `index_sequence`:

```
template <std::size_t...> struct index_sequence {};
template <std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is> struct make_index_sequence : make_index_sequence<N-1, N-1, Is...> {};
template <std::size_t... Is> struct make_index_sequence<0, Is...> : index_sequence<Is...> {};
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/31475fcc1b873a67)

Comment: Possibly the OP wants to pop the arguments off the front before feeding it to the functions; this is easy by making `passArgs` take two `template<class RandomAccessIterator>`s, and have it return the `RandomAccessIterator` that is one-past-the-last-used.

Comment: Thanks for this solution, but is it possible in C++11, not C++14?

Comment: @Mayhem yes, just replace `index_sequence` with any custom implementation you like, [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/31475fcc1b873a67)

Comment: Thanks very much! Can you just add the C++11 replacement of `index_sequence` in the answer for completeness?